# How can I use a downloaded font in HTMLl/CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Beginner developer here! I want to use the Sansation font for my website. I downloaded and installed the font on my pc. But I couldn't find anything about the ways I could use this font in HTML/CSS to apply it to my website.

Comment: Upload it, then use @font-face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using fonts the easy way

The way i prefer to apply a custom font to my website is to link it with a html `link` tag or a css `@import` rule, because this is simply one of the easiest ways of using a custom font.

Here is an example of the html `link` tag which should be placed inside of your html `<head>` tag.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

And if you prefer to do it in a CSS file you can use the `@import` rule.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap');
```

Finally you need to use this css rule to specify the font family you want to use.

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

The example i gave you in this answer are fonts from the GoogleFonts website. It's one of the best websites for custom fonts out there.
https://fonts.google.com/